# Laravel not an object

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to use _construct in Laravel with bellow code

```
class SongsController extends Controller {

    private $song;

    public function _construct(Song $song){

        $this->song=$song;
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $songs=$this->song->get();
        return view('songs',compact('songs'));
    }
  }
```

but in line: `$songs=$this->song->get();` i get an error:
Call to a member function get() on a non-object.
What i do wrong? Btw its run perfect if i do this:

```
public function index(Song $song)
    {
        $songs=$song->get();
        return view('songs',compact('songs'));
    }
```

Comment: `_construct` must be `__construct`

Comment: Ohh god.. i spend an hour+ for that and finally it was the second _ ...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Federico noted in the comments the proper syntax for php constructers is double underscore `__` not `_`:

```
public function __construct(Song $song) {
    $this->song=$song;
}
```